# Word2vec Model size is very small and it is not recognizing words

Tags: python, python-3.x, word2vec, gensim, word-embedding

I trained my `word2vec` model using the `gensim` package on **6.4 GB text data** which is preprocessed using the following code snippet :

```
def read_input(input_file):
  with open(input_file, "r") as inp:
    inp_str = inp.read()

  inp_str = inp_str.strip('\n')
  inp_str = re.sub(r'\n', ' ', inp_str)
  lowercase = inp_str.lower()
  punc = lowercase.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))

  return (punc.translate(str.maketrans('','','1234567890')))

def read_(input_file):
  return( gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(input_file, deacc=True, min_len=3))          

doc = read_input('../train1.txt')
documents = read_(doc)
logging.info ("Done reading data file")
```

But every time I  train the model, its size is **147 Kb** which doesn't seems right and when I tried generating vectors from the trained model it says :

```
KeyError: "word 'type' not in vocabulary"
```

The following is the code I used for training my word2vec model :

```
old_model = Word2Vec.load('../word2vec_model')
old_model.train(documents, total_examples=old_model.corpus_count, epochs=7)

old_model.save('../word2vec_model1')

logging.info ("Saved the new word2vec model")
```

Please help me resolving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The size is small, may be because when you are setting the parameters of the model, you may have used a large value for **min_count** parameter.
Try reducing the value in min_count and retrain the model